# Bumping a (tagged) post to the top of archives

Tags: tags, archives

One of my WordPress sites is a monthly newsletter sent out by a small team to a big organisation that employs over 1,000 people. The main site works well, but I'm working on the archive pages just now.

Every month, one article is designated the 'featured post'. It's given pride of place at the top of the homepage. I do this by applying the tag 'featured' to the post. I know there's probably better ways to do this than tags, but I've got 12 non-technical people posting items to this newsletter and this worked for them before custom post types came along.

On index.php, I do this:

```
query_posts(array('tag' => 'featured'));
```

What I'd really like, is to be able to do this on the archives. I'm trying to get it so that, on the monthly archive page, the post tagged 'featured' for that month shows up at the top, followed by the rest of the posts (as normal).

Has anyone else made similar changes to the archive pages before? Google doesn't seem too helpful -- searching for 'wordpress customize archive' just throws up a few CSS tutorials.

Comment: Brief summary: inside an archive page, I'd like a way to say 'get posts with this tag, but only within the archive date'.

Comment: You're on your way to victory, just use the `year` and `monthnum` arguments when querying. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters don't forget to `exclude` it from the main loop.

Comment: @Soulseekah Done. If you post this as an answer rather than a comment, I'll accept it. Thanks. `query_posts(array('tag' => 'top-left', 'year' => get_the_date( 'Y' ), 'month' => get_the_date( 'm' )));`

Answer (score 1):

The [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) function documentation does give an example on how to filter by time as well. Albeit, small and out of context.

The [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters) documentation give much more information, including on Time Parameters that it accepts. `query_posts` is just a wrapper to methods provided by the global instance of the `WP_Query` class.

So, the correct argument set would be something of this sort:

```
$args = array(
    'tag' => 'the-tag',
    'year' => get_query_var( 'year' ),
    'month' => get_query_var( 'monthnum' )
);
query_posts( $args );
```

[`get_query_var`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) will usually contain the year and the month for an archive.